# How to show Category and subcategory in PickerView IOS

Tags: ios

I want to show Food category and subcategory on drop down style.
But drop down not possible in IOS so we used PickerView.
So please how to implement category and subcategory display on PickerView.
We are fetch category and subcategory on JSON file.

Comment: UIPIckerView with 2 components? Category in one, subcategory in other?

Answer (score 0):

I have made a project: http://www.filedropper.com/dependentcomponentpickerview

I hope it will help you!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can add/implement the picker view from the library on .xib(nib) file. After adding the picker view you need to define the datasource and delegate and then you can write your own code to build the view.

Note --> Dont forget to define and write the codes at the end of .m file of " #pragma mark Picker Data Source/Delegate Source Methods.

The below Apple developers page can be helpful for you:

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/search/index.php?Search=Picker